# The difference between Taylor seires in Evan's PDE book and Lee's intro to smooth manifolds

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, taylor-expansion, smooth-manifolds

I am not an expert in Taylor series, and I would like to learn more about it. But I am confused about two versions of multivariate Taylor series that I found. The first one is in Lawrence Evan's "Partial Differential Equations", which reads:

$f(x) = \sum\limits_{|\alpha| \leq k} \frac{1}{\alpha!}D^\alpha f(0)x^\alpha + O(|x|^{k+1}) \text{ as } x \to 0$

And the other version is what I found in John M. Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds", which reads:

$f(a) + \sum\limits_{m=1}^k\frac{1}{m!}\sum\limits_{I:|I|=m}\partial_I f(a)(x-a)^I+ R_k(x)$,

where $R_k(x) = \frac{1}{k!}\sum\limits_{I:|I|=k+1}(x-a)^I \int\limits^1_0 (1-t)^k \partial_If(a+t(x-a)) dt$

Here, as you see, there is no mention of the behavior of $R_k$ as $x\to a$.

There is an obvious difference in notations, but it is not what causing the problem for me. The quantity $\frac{1}{\alpha!} \neq \frac{1}{k!}$ (at least not necessarily).

Both versions seem to be true, but are they the same and I am missing something?

I would highly appreciate it if you answer this for me.

Comment: Probably the best way to understand this is to go back to the 1D case, and read about the various forms of the "remainder" -- the "Integral form", which is what Lee's using, and the two other forms whose names I forget -- maybe one is "Cauchy"? As for $\alpha!$ vs $k!$, did you mean $m!$ instead of $k!$? If so, they don't seem so different to me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this should clarify everything. As for $\alpha!$ vs $k!$, I used the exact notations from the books, so things are not easily comparable. Anyways, by $\alpha!$, Evans means $\alpha_1! \cdot \alpha_2! \cdots \alpha_n!$. On the other hand $k! = |\alpha|! =(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2+ \dots+ \alpha_n)!$

Comment: @JohnHughes The problem is that $\alpha$ is a vector, so $\alpha!=\prod \alpha_i!$.  In this case, $m!$ appears to equal $|\alpha|!$.  To remedy this, there should be a multinomial coefficient in Lee's version $\binom{m}{I}$, which would cancel the $m!$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that Evans and I use different multi-index conventions. For Evans, if he's working in $\mathbb R^n$, a multi-index $\alpha$ always represents an $n$-tuple of nonnegative integers. If $\alpha = (\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$, then 
\begin{align*}
x^\alpha &= (x_1)^{\alpha_1}\dots (x_n)^{\alpha_n},\\
D^\alpha &= \frac{\partial^{\alpha_1 + \dots + \alpha_n}}{\partial x_1^{\alpha_1}\dots \partial x_n^{\alpha_n}}.
\end{align*}
In other words, the $j$-th position in the multi-index tells how many derivatives are being taken with respect to the $j$-th variable.

For me, on the other hand, a multi-index $I$ can be any length, and is made up of integers from $1$ to $n.$ If $I = (i_1,\dots,i_k)$, then 
\begin{align*}
x^I &= (x_{i_1})\cdot \dots \cdot (x_{i_k}),\\
\partial_I &= \frac{\partial^k}{\partial x_{i_1}\dots \partial x_{i_k}}.
\end{align*}
In other words, the $j$-th position tells which variable the $j$-th derivative is taken with respect to.

These different conventions result in different ways of bookkeeping for all the terms in the Taylor polynomial. In Evans's notation, when you take a particular mixed $k$-th derivative, it only shows up once in the sum, but it shows up with a coefficient of the form $\alpha! = (\alpha_1)!\dots(\alpha_n)!$, just from the formula for taking derivatives of a polynomial. On the other hand, in my notation, each $k$-th derivative shows up multiple times, one for each possible ordering of the indices, and each of these gets a coefficient depending on which variables are differentiated how many times. But magically, when you add the terms all up, the overall coefficient turns out to be exactly $k!$. (You don't have to believe in magic -- just follow the proof in my book! It's nothing but integration by parts.)

Comment: Cool to see one of the relevant authors answer here. I don't think Evans is on here, though?